# Logical Delete from an EJB database

Tags: postgresql, seam, ejb

I have a database and the tables in this database are interconnected. 
I am using seam and EJB to process data inside these tables in the database. 
My backend database is postgres.

Now what I am trying to do is that I want to delete data from one table but I am getting a postgres sql error which tells me that I am violating rules. 
I understand that I can delete this database logically 

- A situation where I have to delete the database and set a flag.

But I don't know how to do this. I know this is simple but pardon me. I dont know it. Any help will be appreciative. Below is the code that I am using. Thank you for your help.

```
public void delete() throws java.sql.SQLException {
  System.out.println("I got here FIRST");   
  user =em.find(Subscriber.class, subscriber.getId()); //ADDED LATER
  users.remove(subscriber.getId());
  em.remove(subscriber);
  userList(); 
 }
```

Comment: Please show the exception you are getting and also please inform us what kind of persistence manager you are using, (Hibernate, TopLink etc)

Comment: What kind of rules are you violating?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see at the first glance, is that you perhaps want to delete the user you are querying?

Thus, change `em.remove(subscriber);` to `em.remove(user);` //which you load from the find method

**Update**

Without know what kind of `flag` you want to check against, let me demonstrate how you can do this:

Lets assume User has a boolean field called disabled, and you want to only remove disabled users.

```
if(user.isDisabled()) 
   em.remove(user);
```

So you only remove users if `flag` is true.

Comment: Thanks for your response Shervin, you are correct. This code works. users=subscribers and user=subscriber but I want a situation where when I do em.remove(user), it will only remove it logically with a flag set to true or false and if its false it will be removed but will not cause me to violate any postgres rule. any help. Than kyou

Comment: Thank you Shervin. Although I have not tested this and I will still test it. But I will like to ask if this is possible. Remember that my user is a whole entity on its own. How then can I make it a flag since it is an ejb entity? Is it possible that if I just do it this way it will work or do I need to cast it to boolean? Thanks for your response. It seems that I am getting there.

Comment: @sammy: You need to modify your code accordingly. If you could tell me what this `flag` is you are using, then I can help you. Also, if you encounter that adding new methods gives you problems in your entity bean, you can add the annotation `@Transient` on top of the method. This will tell your persistence provider to skip this method.